# VSCODE on WSL 1/Ubuntu-22.04 getting &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n" trying to debug hello world

Tags: gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Have VSCODE on a Windows 10 machine, WSL with Ubuntu installed and am trying to debug a basic C++ app. Getting the error

Full output in VSCODE terminal is:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling 
terminal: Operation not permitted\n 
[1] + Done                       
"/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi -- 
tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft- 
MIEngine-In-itqt2xnq.hf2" 
1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-mc0wqh2g.wfn"
```

Versions:

```
VSCODE 1.76.2
Windows: Version 10.0.19045.2728
WSL - When I start VSCode it warms me that I have WSL 1 installed, 
I don't know how to get the specific build
Ubuntu 22.04
G++ 11.3.0
GDB 12.1
```

I've seen many verions of this questions asked and several answers, and none have helped me.

Some of them suggest setting the terminal that GDB opens.

I believe the line:

```
"externalConsole": false,
```

from my launch.json, which is pasted below, is supposed to tell GDB to launch the instrinsic `VSCODE` terminal.

I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. The app compiles and runs fine from the built-in `VSCODE` terminal.

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/hello",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello",
            // "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Provide backtrace to all threads",
                    "text": "thread apply all bt",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Catch an exception when thrown",
                    "text": "catch throw",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Ignore SIG34",
                    "text": "handle SIG34 nostop pass noprint",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

I have the C++ extensions 1.14.5 installed, WSL extension 17.6M installed.

```
 Selecting "Debug C/C++ file"
 Selecting "Run C/C++ file" gives the same error
 Typing ./hello from the VSCODE terminal works
```

full terminal output is:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling 
terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
[1] + Done                       
"/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi -- 
tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft- 
 MIEngine-In-itqt2xnq.hf2" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-mc0wqh2g.wfn"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
you can use GDB in the terminal like this:

```
gdb your_program
break main_line
run
```

then I get:
A fatal error internal to GDB has been detected, further
debugging is not possible.  GDB will now terminate.

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.

This error means that GDB itself has encountered a serious problem and is unable to continue debugging the program. It is recommended to follow the link provided in the error message and report this error on the official GDB page. Meanwhile, you can try using a different version of GDB or attempt running GDB on a different operating system or machine to see if the problem can be resolved.

---

I come back!
I have already solved this problem,this is a bug in gdb,you can update the WSL1 to WSL2.

you can use it:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/wsl/install-manual)

Enter in the terminal of Windows (requires administrator privileges)

```
netsh winsock reset
```

this will solve the problem.

Comment: I hava already solved this problem.